# Wait for an ajax request to complete in React?

Tags: ajax, reactjs

Below is my react code I want that firstly the ajax code should execute then the rest of the code should execute.

**expected output in console:**

inside ajax

outside ajax

**current output in console :**

outside ajax

inside ajax

```
import React from 'react';
import request from 'superagent'

 const UserItems = () => {
 request.get('http://localhost:4000/user/1/items.json') 
 .then((res, err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("errror found") 
    }
  var data = JSON.parse(res.text)
  console.log("inside ajax")
  console.log(data)

  })

 console.log("outside ajax")
 console.log(data)
};

export default UserItems;
```

Any suggestion !!!

Comment: If you want to block some code from executing unless and until the ajax request has finished processing, put that code (whatever is outside) within `then()`. Else, the `console.log("outside")` will always execute first since the code within `then()` will execute only once a response has been received.

Comment: @SangeethSudheer : earlier I did this but it gives me error stating

` Warning: UserItems(...): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.`

Answer (score 1):

As hainguyen points out, ajax is typically asynchronous so the code afterwards will run until the request is complete, at which time the inner function is executed.  So the outer console logs will almost certainly run first in your code.  While there are ways around this as hainguyen points out, most recommend against it.  Ajax is something which takes time, and therefore your code structure should reflect that.  If you ever find yourself wanting to run code while the ajax request is in process, you might dislike a synchronous structure.  My "I wait for no one" log shows the power of an asynchronous approach since that logic will run quickly while you would normally be waiting on the request without being able to do anything.

Rather than make it synchronous why not use functions to handle the asynchronous behavior better like wrapping whatever you want to run after the inside console log in a function: (I called it outside())  This will output "inside ajax", "outside ajax".  This way you can create dependencies on your ajax return and still have the option for running stuff in the meantime.

```
import React from 'react';
import request from 'superagent';

 const UserItems = () => {
 request.get('http://localhost:4000/user/1/items.json') 
 .then((res, err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("errror found");
    }
    var data = JSON.parse(res.text);
    console.log("inside ajax");
    console.log(data);
    outside();
   });

  function outside(){
    console.log("outside ajax");
    console.log(data);
  }

  console.log("I wait for no one, run me as quick as possible!");
};

export default UserItems;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about request library but ajax is async by default. If you want ajax perform sync request, you should do something like this:

```
function getRemote() {
   return $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: remote_url,
     async: false
   }).responseText;
}
```

Important line: `async: false`

Comment: Its jquery convention to do this I'm using react with superagent for api calls.

Comment: You should look at library API document, I think it should have that setting.